# Fetch the IP address of sender in Windows Phone 7.5

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

My architecture involves multiple phones connecting to a Windows Phone (running 7.5 version). I would like to get the IP address of the phone which sends the request. I have seen various forums but could not get sufficient information.

Can you please let me know how to find the IP address of the sender?

Answer (score 2):

Kishan, You need to make http request to get the IP of current user in windows Phone 7 as there is no direct method or API in WP7 to get the client IP.
Here is the detailed post on that how to get IP of user.

http://compiledexperience.com/windows-phone/tutorials/my-ip